# rabin-karp algorithm using rolling hash exclisive OR

Tags: algorithm, rabin-karp

I'm trying to understand this question :

In the following questions, take the character values as:
A: 0
C: 1
G: 2
T: 3

In the text GATTACA, the hash value computed using exclusive
or for the substring GAT is 1. What is the hash value for
the substring ATT?

l google rabin-karp using exclusive OR , and nothing .
can someone help me to understand ?
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't think  you should use XOR for finding hash values, the classical way gives better hash quality. However if you want compute hash value using rolling hash, you can do something like this:

```
hash(ATT) = hash(GAT) xor hash(G) xor hash(T).
```

Which is 0 by the way. You get 0 if you xor two same values so in order to get rid of first G, you need to xor it again with GAT.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff about Rabin-Karp is quite nice, but completely irrelevant here. Concentrate on the relevant part, which is:

> A=0, T=3
>   Find the hash of the string `ATT` with a simple `xor` as hash-function.

The answer to that would be `A xor T xor T = A = 0`. Or if you absolutely insist on using a rolling hash-function `hash(ATT) = hash(GAT) xor G xor T = 1 xor 2 xor 3 = 0`.